# best way to load scripts dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a project where I've had to greatly widgetize my code. As such, I'm loading 5 pages of JS dynamically into the DOM. The problem I'm having though is that I don't have a way to check and wait for these scripts to be loaded. If it takes them a second to get pushed up into the DOM, then my script tries to run, but fails when it calls on them.

Here's an example of how I'm embedding my scripts.

```
var script_tag2 = document.createElement('script');
script_tag2.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
script_tag2.setAttribute("src","http://www.freeptools.com/mapster/js/three.min.js");
(document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag2);
```

This inserts it into the DOM, but I dont' have a way to pause my code until it's done. Has anyone run into this before? I'm trying to come up with a best practices for this, but coming up short.

Comment: jquery's `getScript` allows a callback to be called when the script is loaded (the idea behind I think is the `onload` event of the `script` dom element)

Comment: If it is tagged jQuery, why don't you use [getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)?

Comment: __$(document).load(function() {...});__ should work...

Comment: I'd suggest to take a look on require.js ( http://requirejs.org/ ) and approaches used by Twitter Flight Framework ( https://flightjs.github.io/ ) .

Answer (score 1):

Use `jQuery.getScript`

```
jQuery.getScript("http://www.freeptools.com/mapster/js/three.min.js")
    .done(function() {
        /* yay, all good, do something */
    })
    .fail(function() {
        /* boo, fall back to something else */
});
```